# HtmlInputCheckBox in Repeater always not checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, unchecked, html-input

i'm using a HtmlInputCheckBox in a repeater by adding

```
<input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" runat="server" value='<%# Eval ("userid") %>' />
```

to repeater->ItemTemplate->table->tr->td and in the server side i'm using

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < UserRepeater.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var chkBox = UserRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1") as HtmlInputCheckBox;

            if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

i'm not programatically setting any checkbox to set - i'm checking them on the web page during test.
my var checkbox is always inchecked {Value = "1,2,3,4" Checked = false}, thx for helping me with that.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, for example where is your for loop? in a button_click handler maybe? you are not programatically setting any checkbox to set - so are you checking them on the web page during test? what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you populating your repeater - if you are doing it in page_load make sure it is protected for postbacks:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // populate your data
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is assuming you are working with viewstate on - which is the case by default.

Answer (score 0):

This may be to do with when you bind your repeater.  If you are binding on Page_Load, the check boxes will be created after viewstate and post variables have been restored, so the value won't be on your checkboxes.

If possible, move the data bind to Page_Init; as this happens before viewstate/post values are restored your checkboxes will get the right values assigned.  If you can't bind on Page_Init, then @Aristos's answer will do.

Comment: thank you @varangian_12 i fix it by binding repeater in if (!IsPostBack){} in Page_Load.